# A purely css-bassed dropdown menu with a close button

Tags: css

So I have a simple dropdown that activates on hover or focus (hover for desktop, and focus for mobile, which works great.

My problem is I am trying to add a close button to the dropdown but I can't seem to figure out how to achieve this. What I want to do is on focus of span (close... I can replace with a button if that helps) maybe loose focus of the parent div so it closes. The close button is only shown on mobile, because the dropdown is 100% and 100% height so there's no way to click out to lose focus unlike the desktop website

Here is what I have up to now:

```css
.group:hover .group-hocus\:block,
.group:focus .group-hocus\:block {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <button>open</button>
  <div class="group-hocus:block hidden">
    <span style="padding: 5px;">x Close</span><br />
    Content Here...
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible with just CSS, if so, how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `focus-within` and make your close element focusable by adding tabindex to it:

```css
.group:hover .group-hocus\:block,
.group:focus .group-hocus\:block {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.group-hocus\:block {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:3px solid red;
}
.group-hocus\:block span {
  font-size:25px;
  color:green;
  cursor:pointer;
  outline:none;
}
.group-hocus\:block:focus-within  {
 display:none!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <button>open</button>
  <div class="group-hocus:block hidden">
    <span style="padding: 5px;" tabindex="-1">x Close</span><br />
    Content Here...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great for desktop, but when you open chrome/responsive, and tap the (close button) it re-opens.

Answer (score -2):

Try googling the CSS checkbox hack, thank me later ;)

In a nutshell, it uses an inputs checkbox and a label. hide the checkbox, style the label to be a 'X'.

Then in CSS you can use input:checked .menu-open {blah blah blah}.

You can quite easily hide this or change it with mediaQueries